# Ruby on Rails: What prevents a user from adding a form field to a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a form in Rails, and I only want to expose certain fields to the user, how do I prevent the user from hacking the form and adding additional fields to insert unwanted data?

For example, say I have a task.rb model with the following columns: name, description, internal_notes. For the public form in "app/views/tasks/new.html.erb", I only want to expose the public fields like so:

```
form
  name:
  description:
/form
```

How can I prevent the user from hacking the form and doing this:

```
form
  name:
  description:
  internal_notes:  <--- inserted by user (e.g. through Google Chrome Elements)
/form
```

For example, the user can enter `<input type="text" name="task[internal_notes]" />` into the form, and submit the unwanted data.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the why of the existence of two very useful ActiveRecord class methods:

- [attr_protected](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_protected)
- [attr_accesible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible)

Check the documentation about [MassAssignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) to understand it better.

Comment: one should also mention `protect_from_forgery` and the according xsrf token.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem as it's going be the standard solution for MassAssignment protectionn in Rails 4

Comment: Wonderful tip. Much appreciated. Thanks Dan :)